# filepicker.io Javascript API calls result in unsafe javascript errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filepicker.io

I'm currently using AngularJS, and I would like to call filePicker.pickAndStore from my Upload controller. Any call to a filepicker.io API function results in an "Unsafe Javascript attempt" error:

> The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a > protocol of 'http'. Procols must match.

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('app').controller('UploadCtrl', ['$scope, function ($scope) {
    $scope.uploadFiles = function() {
        filepicker.pickAndStore({mimetype:'image/*'},{},function(files){console.log(files)},function(err){console.log(err)});
    }
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" ng-click="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
```

The error displays in the console as soon as I click the button and the filepicker modal shows up.

I can still select and upload files, but I don't know why this error should occur since I am including the http filepicker source in my project.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known chrome/webkit issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76748).
This is happening on any cross domain iframe that adds a flash  tag to itself through JavaScript (technique used by filepicker).

Last news from filepicker team: They are working on circumventing this.

Comment: Thank you, I was worried that I was doing something wrong. It all seems to work fine, but I wanted to make sure that it wasn't just me.