# Filepicker.io Cross-Domain Restrictions [Rails4 + Turbolinks]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cross-domain, ruby-on-rails-4, filepicker.io, turbolinks

I'm having issues with Filepicker.io on my Rails 4 site.  Specifically, I am occasionally getting the following JavaScript error message (about 50% of the time) when I try to upload a file via the Filepicker.io widget.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.filepicker.io" from accessing a frame with origin "https://salesbeach.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

This happens in both Chrome and Firefox.  My assumption is that Filepicker.io should be, but is not, returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.  However, I have used Filepicker.io on other sites without this issue, and I wonder if Turbolinks could be the culprit.

### Diagnostic Information

My JavaScript call is:

```
filepicker.pickAndStore({mimetypes: mimeTypes},{},function(fpfiles) { ... }
```

and I load the Filepicker library (in the HTML `<head>`) via:

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js', function() {
      filepicker.setKey('#{MY_API_KEY}');
    });
  })
})();
```

The `<iframe>` has the following HTTP request/response (from Chrome debug tools):

**Request**

```
Request URL:https://www.filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:www.filepicker.io
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://salesbeach.com/playground
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1566.2 Safari/537.36
```

**Response**

```
Response Headers
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:857
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 19 Jul 2013 19:23:22 GMT
P3P:CP='IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT'
P3P:CP="OTI DSP COR ADM DEV TAIo PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT COM INT NAV"
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Also, I have included a playground that reproduced the bug: [Playground Environment](https://salesbeach.com/playground)

Comment: Maybe my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18142900 helps? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762697/how-to-get-filepicker-and-turbolinks-to-play-well-together)

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modified from: [filepicker.io Javascript API calls result in unsafe javascript errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192466/filepicker-io-javascript-api-calls-result-in-unsafe-javascript-errors)

This is a known [chrome/webkit](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76748) issue. This is happening on any cross domain iframe that adds a flash tag to itself through JavaScript (technique used by Ink File Picker). It shouldn't affect functionality and is a result of them trying to use flash detection to see if the webcam picture and video recording options are possible.