# filepicker.io blocked iframe in Chrome

Tags: javascript, security, filepicker.io

Trying to use the [inkfilepicker](http://inkfilepicker.com) and getting some security errors in Chrome (works in Safari though).

`Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.filepicker.io" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:5150".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192466/filepicker-io-javascript-api-calls-result-in-unsafe-javascript-errors) is probably the closest question on SO, but it has no answer.

Comment: The SO post that you mentioned seems to say: 1. File Picker works even though this warning comes up. 2. It's a known Chrome issue and 3. they're working on it. Is there something in particular you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. When an error is encounted, a new window is created rather than using a modal. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: You're hitting one of the fallback mechanisms that it has when it's not allowed to communicate between your page and the modal iframe. If you have "Block third-party cookies and site data" set in Chrome. Try unchecking that setting in Chrome/Advanced Settings/Content Settings/

Comment: We are also seeing this issue. Anyone has any ideas. I checked my chrome advance settings and i have the checkbox unchecked for "Blocked third party cookies and site data".

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the LastPass chrome extension installed?  They do not play nicely with each other.

Comment: oh no!! why you no work with lastpass. This seems hella random